# How to create a simple diary/journaling website with Django?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I may have bit off more than I can chew. I am looking for a tutorial or some guidance on creating a journaling/diary website using Django. I am trying to create a website where the user logs in, has some simple dashboard, and the ability to submit journal entries that would be saved into a database for later analysis. I was wondering if anyone could provide guidance on where to start or literature to begin looking at to make this project successful.

I have tried multiple methods from: modifying different repos, modifying tutorials, and starting from scratch. Currently I am using the Firefox/Mozilla django tutorial that I am modifying as I go.

Comment: Wagtail is a CRM system built on top of Django: https://wagtail.io/

Comment: Is it a CRM or a CMS? :P